# Run selenium test using firefox on LInux

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox, jenkins

Linux Ubuntu
Firefox 43
Selenium 2.53.1

I installed Xvfb then I did something like this

> Xvfb :77 -ac

and

> export DISPLAY=:77

then I checked if firefox works on linux ($firefox) ->  launched without error, and stay running until I kill it with Control-C

Now I try to start my selenium tests using Jenkins. I indicated my DISPLAY but when I run tests I get:

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

```
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
at com.rulefinancial.testing.webdriver.LocalFirefoxDriverProvider.getNewWebDriver(LocalFirefoxDriverProvider.java:16)
at com.rulefinancial.testing.MainTest.beforeClass(MainTest.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:178)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
```

Can anyone tell me what happens here? How to solve this problem?
It works fine on windows - I mean ff 43 and selenium 2.53.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the parameters of the X virtual frame buffer, when you start it. I think the issue is here. For me it worked, I did it step by step following [headless execution of selenium tests in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins) blog post.

Comment: I tried a lot from different websites. Solutions were quite similar to yours but i has never worked so I was a little bit discouraged but I must say article which you indicated is perfect and everything works great :) :)
Thanks a lot @Konstantin